# How to clear the facebook user data after logout in android app

Tags: android

[Following this](http://www.kpbird.com/2013/03/android-login-using-facebook-sdk-30.html)

working with facebook sdk 3.0 ,here after successful login able to get facebook user email and displayed it in textview but after logout how to clear the data. here attaching screenshot after logout.[image: screenshot after logout]

Here placing code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private TextView lblEmail;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lblEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblEmail);

        LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.authButton);
        authButton.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Error " + error.getMessage());
            }
        });
        // set permission list, Don't foeget to add email
        authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("basic_info", "email"));
        // session state call back event
        authButton.setSessionStatusCallback(new Session.StatusCallback() {

            @Override
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                    Exception exception) {

                if (session.isOpened()) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Access Token" + session.getAccessToken());
                    Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session,
                            new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,
                                        Response response) {
                                    if (user != null) {
                                        Log.i(TAG, "User ID " + user.getId());
                                        Log.i(TAG,
                                                "Email "
                                                        + user.asMap().get(
                                                                "email"));
                                        lblEmail.setText(user.asMap()
                                                .get("email").toString());
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                }

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode,
                resultCode, data);
    }

}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

followed this link to fix this issue

```
`private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    if (state.isOpened()) {
        userInfoTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else if (state.isClosed()) {
        userInfoTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}`
```

,[here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/fetch-user-data/)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code. Set a button and on click of that button close and clear the token information which is done in `logoutFacebook()` method and after that you have to reach `signIn` screen so you have to use `launchSignIn()` method in which you'll b navigating to `signIn` screen and clearing the tasks using 
         Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK  | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK

```
package com.example.integration;

import com.facebook.Session;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ThirdActivity extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.welcome);

        Button logoutBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logout_btn);
        logoutBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                logout();
            }
        });
        Toast.makeText(ThirdActivity.this, "In Third Activity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void logout(){
        logoutFacebook(ThirdActivity.this);
        launchSignIn(ThirdActivity.this);
    }

    private void launchSignIn(Context context) {
        if (context != null) {
            // Launch LoginActivity
            Intent loginActivity = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            loginActivity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                    | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            context.startActivity(loginActivity);
        }

    }

    private void logoutFacebook(Context context) {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session != null) {
            if (!session.isClosed()) {
                session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
                // clear your preferences if saved
            }
        } else {
            session = new Session(context);
            Session.setActiveSession(session);
            session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
            // clear your preferences if saved
        }

    }   

}
```